# PHP detmine numbers in between two numbers then query

Tags: php, mysql

This should be simple but I can't figure it out

```
<?php
$testid = 240;
$curid = 251;

$cal = $curid - $testid;
echo $cal;

?>
```

I want to determine the numbers in between two other numbers so for this example it detects there are 11 numbers in between the $testid and $curid, but i dont need it to do that.

I need it to literally figure the numbers in between $curid - $testid which in this example would be 241, 242, 243... all the way to 251 then i need to create a loop with those numbers and do a query below with each one

```
$cal = $curid - $testid;
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wall WHERE id='".$cal."'")

// and for each number mysql should out put each data field with those numbers.
```

Thanks again, love you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This assumes that `$testid` is smaller than `$curid`:

```
$testid = 240;
$curid = 251;
$numbers = range(($testid + 1), ($curid));
$query = 'SELECT * FROM wall WHERE id IN (' . implode(', ', $numbers). ')';
```

If I `print $query;` I get:

```
SELECT * FROM wall WHERE id IN
    (241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251)
```

So just do your query:

```
mysql_query($query);
```

More about [`range()`](https://www.php.net/range) and [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/implode)

Comment: Thanks again for your response, im probably going to end up combing these two answers because i forgot to mention i need to include all the numbers in between plus the current one which in this example is 251 and yours does that

Comment: Updated the answer to include `$curid`

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php - great example.

Answer (score 4):

You could make a list of numbers with `range()` as @artlung suggestions, but it's possible that the list is very long, which would not be an efficient query.

Why not use [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)?

```
$testid = 240;
$curid = 251;

$query = "SELECT * FROM wall WHERE id BETWEEN {$testid}+1 AND {$curid}";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach (range(240, 251) as $n) {
    mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wall WHERE id='".$n."'")
}
```

Also, you can make it with one query..