# Multiple where clauses in one mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I want to get all results which these queries give with one query;

```
1- $query = mysql_query("select * from table where view='1'");
2- $query = mysql_query("select * from table where view='2'");
3- $query = mysql_query("select * from table where view='3'");
4- $query = mysql_query("select * from table where view='4'");
.
.
.
999999- $query = mysql_query("select * from table where view='999999'");
```

How can I do that easily?

Comment: use `and` and `or` in your case use `or`

Comment: Do not use mysql_* functions:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189

Comment: Is it a static list or `1` to `999999`?

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP detmine numbers in between two numbers then query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035378/php-detmine-numbers-in-between-two-numbers-then-query)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several ways.  For this extreme case (or any range) use `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE view BETWEEN 1 AND 999999
```

If not a range use `IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE view IN (1,2,3,4,999999)
```

Comment: Thank you, I need one more thing left to do what I want is how to get duplicate results once. I mean, if there are 3 results have "7 views", l want to get 1 result (it gives the same result 3 times, i need just 1 time). How can i do this?

Comment: Using `SELECT *` you can't use `DISTINCT` but you could do `SELECT * FROM table WHERE view BETWEEN 1 AND 999999 GROUP BY view`

Comment: Omg it works! Thank you so much! I really appreciate all your help and support :))

Answer (score 3):

You can use a pair of `>=` and `<=` operators:

```
$query = 
mysql_query("select * from table where view >= '1' AND view <= '999999'");
```

Answer (score 2):

if it's serialized numbers

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from table where view between 1 and 999999");
```

if it's discrete numbers

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from table where view in(1, 2, 3, 10, 16, 88)");
```

also it's not recommend to use mysql_query it's [removed](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7) from php 7 use instead [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) with preapre to prevent SQL injection

here is example for pdo

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("select * from table where view between ? and ?");
$query->execute([1,99999]);
```